# In which tag the .css should be placed in an asp.net master page?

Tags: asp.net

following is the code of my master page. I want to put my css files here. But not sure where. Please see the following-

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeMaster.master.cs" Inherits="LeaveManager.EmloyeeUI.EmployeeMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <====== here ? ===========>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <====== or, here ?? ===========>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <====== Reference CSS files here ===========>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

That way it will be on all pages. And if you want to override it for a single page, you can create the new style only on that ASPX page and it will override the 'default' styles you put in the master page.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop the style sheet in design view of master page.

OR place before head element:

```
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it within the contentplaceholder because you can overide it in other pages if you want.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/CSSFile.css" type="text/css" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Master Page  refrence the css files in the below location

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
      **<====== Reference CSS Files Here===========>**
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above or Below the head content placeholder.

Comment: <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
 css goes here ? 
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: css goes here ? 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
or  css goes here ? If you want to override the css place it inside the content place holder. Normally I don't think that situation will occur.